# utf8mb4 characters not surviving "LOAD DATA INFILE"

Tags: mysql, utf-8, utf8mb4

I have a csv file containing some characters that lie outside Unicode BMP, for example the character . They are SMP characters, so they need to be stored in `utf8mb4` charset and `utf8mb4_general_ci` collation in MySQL instead of `utf8` charset and `utf8_general_ci` collation.

So here are my SQL queries.

```
MariaDB [tweets]> set names 'utf8mb4';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [tweets]> create table test (a text) collate utf8mb4_general_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

MariaDB [tweets]> insert into test (a) values ('');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [tweets]> select * from test;
+------+
| a    |
+------+
|      |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

No warnings. Everything is right. Now I want to load that csv file. For test, the file has only one line.

```
MariaDB [tweets]> load data local infile 't.csv' into table wzyboy character set utf8mb4 fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n\n' (tweet_id,in_reply_to_status_id,in_reply_to_user_id,retweeted_status_id,retweeted_status_user_id,timestamp,source,text,expanded_urls);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 7 warnings (0.01 sec)      
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 7
```

The warning message is:

```
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x80\x80' for column 'text' at row 1      |
```

All my working environments (OS, Termianl, etc) use UTF-8. I have specified `utf8mb4` in everyplace I could think up of, and if I manually `INSERT INTO` it works just fine. However, when I use `LOAD DATA INFILE [...] CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 [...]` it just fails with error "Incorrect string value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

It was a mistake. During the experiment, I just `TRUNCATE TABLE` but not re-create it. So the database and the table are both `utf8mb4`, but the columns are still `utf8`...